# Get count of rows after a unique date for each row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a 1:1 table (we will call this table 1) which looks like this:

```
| id | date                |  
|----|---------------------|  
| 1  | 2011-01-02 00:00:00 |  
| 2  | 2012-01-02 00:00:00 |
```

I have a second many:1 table (we will call this table 2) which looks like this:

```
| id | date                |  
|----|---------------------|  
| 1  | 2011-01-01 00:00:00 |  
| 1  | 2011-01-02 00:00:00 |  
| 1  | 2011-01-03 00:00:00 |  
| 2  | 2011-12-31 00:00:00 |  
| 2  | 2012-01-01 00:00:00 |  
| 2  | 2012-01-03 00:00:00 |
```

I would like to left join table 1 and table 2 (table 1 is the left table) on id, but I only want the count of dates from table 2 that are greater than or equal to the date column in table 1.

Thus, the resultant table would look like this:

```
| id | date                | count_dates |  
|----|---------------------|-------------|  
| 1  | 2011-01-02 00:00:00 | 2           |  
| 2  | 2012-01-02 00:00:00 | 1           |
```

How can I do this using SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't bother with a left join, just use a sub-query with the appropriate `where` clause e.g.

```
select id, [date]
  , (select count(*) from dbo.Table2 T2 where T2.id = T1.id and T2.[date] >= T1.[date])
from dbo.Table1 T1;
```